# Using instance method to concatenate a list

Tags: python, object, concatenation, instance

I have a class named stock, and I am trying to concatenate quarterly earnings for an object.

```
class Stock :
    def __init__(self,name,report_date,earning,estimate):
        self.Name = name
        self.Report_date = report_date
        self.Earning = [earning]
        self.Estimate = estimate
    def list_append(self,earning):
        self.Earning = [self.Earning,earning]
example = Stock('L',2001,10,10)
example.list_append(11)
example.list_append(12)
example.list_append(13)
```

Like this.
So that finally i want the output of example.Earning = [10,11,12,13].
But the output is coming out as example.Earning = [[[[10], 11], 12],13]
I tried the following.

```
self.Earning = (self.Earning).append(earning)
Error = "int" does not have attribute append
```

and

```
self.Earning[-1:] = earning
```

But they are throwing me errors.
How can I get rid of this embedded list([[[10], 11], 12]) and make just one list([10,11,12,13])?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem and get rid of the embedded lists, you can do:

```
def list_append(self,earning):
        self.Earning = [*self.Earning,earning]
```

The * will spread the old list `self.Earnings` and adds `earning` to a new list and assign it to self.Earning

Or just simply use method `append`:

```
def list_append(self,earning):
    self.Earning.append(earning)
```

Comment: thanks. I tried self.Earning.append(earning) as well, but it is keep giving me errors that 'int' does not have attribute append.... but the self.Earning = [*self.Earning,earning] worked perfectly!

Comment: If you kept this line : self.Earning = [earning] in the constructor as it is, it should technically work fine for you. You're Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

The nested lists occur this way because in the initialization of `self.Earning = [earning]` you store each "earning" from an int into a list and later store a list into a list. you could simply rewrite the list_append function.

```
def list_append(self, earning):
    self.Earning.append(earning)
```

Comment: Hi, as I actually tried getting rid of [] and just using append. but getting rid of [] did not work, and self.Earning.append(earning) give me an error. But the answer answer fixed the issue. Thanks for the feedback tho!